# Boost compiling flags gcc errors

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, boost

I have a problem with compiling the example form LenMuse - [this is the example](http://www.lenmus.org/en/lomse/tutorial-1-x11).

I used flags from the provided tutorial and I added a few more to get rid of some other problems, but I can't solve all of them. This is my output from gcc:

```
    /usr/lib/liblomse.so: undefined reference to `boost::thread::start_thread()'
    /usr/lib/liblomse.so: undefined reference to `boost::thread::timed_join(boost::posix_time::ptime const&)'
    /usr/lib/liblomse.so: undefined reference to `boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::ptime const&)'
    /usr/lib/liblomse.so: undefined reference to `boost::thread::~thread()'
```

This is the command I used:

```
gcc interface.cpp -o interface `pkg-config --cflags x11` `pkg-config --cflags liblomse` `pkg-config --libs liblomse` `pkg-config --libs x11` -lstdc++ -lboost_system -I/usr/include/boost/ -lboost_filesystem -lboost_thread
```

I tried to compile with the flag -lboost_thread-mt but gcc cannot find this flag.

I have boost 1.53.0, on the page author says that is required boost 1.43 or higher. My system is ArchLinux.

Comment: please answer your own question rather than edit the question directly with an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by downgrade boost library to version 1.49.0.